# How to use WHERE IN with Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have the following code which gives me the error:

```
Message: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

Code:

```
public function getCount($ids, $outcome)
{
    if (!is_array($ids)) {
        $ids = array($ids);
    }
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->add('select', $qb->expr()->count('r.id'))
       ->add('from', '\My\Entity\Rating r');
    if ($outcome === 'wins') { 
        $qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->in('r.winner', array('?1')));
    }
    if ($outcome === 'fails') {
        $qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->in('r.loser', array('?1')));
    }
    $qb->setParameter(1, $ids);
    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    //die('q = ' . $qb);
    return $query->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

Data (or $ids):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 566
    [1] => 569
    [2] => 571
)
```

DQL result:

```
q = SELECT COUNT(r.id) FROM \My\Entity\Rating r WHERE r.winner IN('?1')
```

Comment: I think this is the recommended way http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#list-of-parameters-conversion

Answer (score 128, accepted):

In researching this issue, I found something that will be important to anyone running into this same issue and looking for a solution.

From the original post, the following line of code:

```
$qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->in('r.winner', array('?1')));
```

Wrapping the named parameter as an array causes the bound parameter number issue. By removing it from its array wrapping:

```
$qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->in('r.winner', '?1'));
```

This issue should be fixed. This might have been a problem in previous versions of Doctrine, but it is fixed in the most recent versions of 2.0.

Comment: I think `$qb->expr()->in()` is only in Doctrine 2 ORM, but not in Doctrine DBAL.

Comment: `$qb->expr()->in()` is indeed in DBAL

Answer (score 420):

The easiest way to do that is by binding the array itself as a parameter:

```
$queryBuilder->andWhere('r.winner IN (:ids)')
             ->setParameter('ids', $ids);
```

Comment: Not only but starting from 2.1

Comment: @MaciejPyszyński +1. The easiest ways are often the best ones!

Comment: Quick mention: This works per default with ->setParameter('ids', $ids) but not with ->setParameters('ids' => $ids). Took me some minutes of debugging.

Comment: to make is work with ->setParameters(...)

```->where('b.status IN (:statuses)')
->setParameters([
                'customerId' => $customerId,
                'storeId'    => $storeId,
                'statuses'   => [Status::OPEN, Status::AWAITING_APPROVAL, Status::APPROVED]
            ]);```

Comment: I would like to point out the importance of also passing the 3th parameter to `setParameter` to force `Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY`

Comment: @MaciejPyszyński that was my friend, extraordinary!

Comment: The easiest way for sure!

Comment: dislike cause i'll  got something like this: `r.winner IN ('1, 2, 3, 4, 5')`

Comment: @VladimirCh It won't just pass an array not a string

Comment: @VladmirCh see the comment from @Luc Wollants. That will signal doctrine to format the parameter correctly `r.winner IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`

Answer (score 81):

and for completion the string solution

```
$qb->andWhere('foo.field IN (:string)');
$qb->setParameter('string', array('foo', 'bar'), \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY);
```

Comment: Can also use \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY if you have an array of integers not strings.

Comment: `\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY` is currently deprecated, use `\Doctrine\DBAL\ArrayParameterType::STRING` instead

Answer (score 28):

I found that, despite what the docs indicate, the only way to get this to work is like this:

```
$ids = array(...); // Array of your values
$qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->in('r.winner', $ids));
```

http://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-dev/browse_thread/thread/fbf70837293676fb

Answer (score 24):

I know it's an old post but may be helpful for someone. I would vote & enhance @Daniel Espendiller answer by addressing the question asked in comments about ints

To make this work for int's in proper way, make sure the values in array are of type int, you can type cast to int before passing...

```
 $qb->andWhere('foo.field IN (:ints)');
 $qb->setParameter('ints', array(1, 2), 
 \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY);
```

Tested for select/delete in symfony 3.4 & doctrine-bundle: 1.8

Answer (score 12):

I know the OP's example is using DQL and the query builder, but I stumbled upon this looking for how to do it from a controller or outside of the repository class, so maybe this will help others.

You can also do a `WHERE IN` from the controller this way:

```
// Symfony example
$ids    = [1, 2, 3, 4];
$repo   = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:RepoName');
$result = $repo->findBy([
    'id' => $ids
]);
```

Comment: That is a perfectly acceptable way to do a where in without using DQL, but his question was in reference to his DQL code. He is doing more than just a simple give me all the things based on these IDs.

Answer (score 8):

This is how I used it:

```
->where('b.status IN (:statuses)')
->setParameters([
                'customerId' => $customerId,
                'storeId'    => $storeId,
                'statuses'   => [Status::OPEN, Status::AWAITING_APPROVAL, Status::APPROVED]
            ]);
```

Answer (score 7):

The best way doing this - especially if you're adding more than one condition - is:

```
$values = array(...); // array of your values
$qb->andWhere('where', $qb->expr()->in('r.winner', $values));
```

If your array of values contains strings, you can't use the setParameter method with an imploded string, because your quotes will be escaped!

Answer (score 7):

Found how to do it in the year of 2016:
https://redbeardtechnologies.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/doctrine-2-dql-in-statement/

Quote:

Here is how to do it properly:

```
$em->createQuery(“SELECT users 
     FROM Entities\User users 
     WHERE 
         users.id IN (:userids)”)
->setParameters(
     array(‘userids’ => $userIds)
);
```

The method `setParameters` will take the given array and implode it properly to be used in the “IN” statement.

Comment: This solved my problem (the parentheses around `:userids` )

Answer (score 4):

```php
$qb->where($qb->expr()->in('r.winner', ':ids'))
    ->setParameter('ids', $ids);
```

Also works with:

```php
$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('r.winner', ':ids'))
    ->setParameter('ids', $ids);
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer:

```
$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('t.user_role_id', [
    User::USER_ROLE_ID_ADVERTISER,
    User::USER_ROLE_ID_MANAGER,
]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this same scenario where I had to do a query against an array of values.

The following worked for me:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#where-clause

```
->andWhereIn("[fieldname]", [array[]])
```

Array data example (worked with strings and integers):

```
$ids = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Query example (Adapt to where you need it):

```
$q = dataTable::getInstance()
    ->createQuery()
    ->where("name = ?",'John')
    ->andWhereIn("image_id", $ids)
    ->orderBy('date_created ASC')
    ->limit(100);

$q->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is years later, working on a legacy site... For the life of me I couldn't get the `->andWhere()` or `->expr()->in()` solutions working.

Finally looked in the Doctrine mongodb-odb repo and found some very revealing tests:

```
public function testQueryWhereIn()
{ 
  $qb = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder('Documents\User');
  $choices = array('a', 'b');
  $qb->field('username')->in($choices);
  $expected = [
    'username' => ['$in' => $choices],
  ];
  $this->assertSame($expected, $qb->getQueryArray());
}
```

It worked for me!

You can find the tests on github [here](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/1.0.x/tests/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Tests/Functional/QueryTest.php). Useful for clarifying all sorts of nonsense.

*Note: My setup is using Doctrine MongoDb ODM v1.0.dev as far as i can make out.*

Answer (score 0):

```
$winnerIds = [1,3,5];
$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('r.winner', ':winnerIds'))
   ->setParameter('winnerIds', $winnerIds)
;
```