# Query builder symfony2 using where IN

Tags: php, symfony

I have the following query builder to add to my entity.

```
'query_builder' => function(\Teln\OperatorBundle\Entity\SoftswitchRepository $er) use ($idBase) {
    $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('t')
    ->where('t.base IN (:id)')
    ->setParameter('id', $idBase);

    return $qb;
},
```

and `$idBase= $builder->getData()->getBases();`

So `$idBase` is a collection.

How to add this to the **where using  IN** ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use WHERE IN with Doctrine 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929036/how-to-use-where-in-with-doctrine-2)

Comment: @venu this is not really a duplicate since the syntax is correct (and was the same from 2nd answer from your dup). Caryl just need to convert the collection to an array of ids.

Comment: hmm yes, apologies for misunderstanding it... +1 for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try to convert the parameter `$idBase` to a simple array with the id's or a string