# How we can write IN statement in where condition of Doctrine

Tags: symfony, dql

I have an array of category, 
how to use IN statement in where class using Doctrine?

Comment: This question has already an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6319643/1607098)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use like this

```
public function searchCategory($target){//$target is an aray(1,2,3)

      $query = $this->getEntityManager()
                    ->createQuery("SELECT abc ct.target as target FROM AdminBundle:ClothingType ct WHERE ct.target IN (:target)")
                     ->setParameter('target',$target['target']);// You can change it as ur requirment 
                     try {
                     return $query->getResult();
                } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
                return null;
                }
```

}

Comment: -1. The code you posted contains both DQL syntax error and a PHP notice. Please, take time to read and test the code you provide.

Comment: I just need concept to write it , working fine for me . @ Touki