# Symfony 2 - Using Doctrine's Collection in DQL

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, repository

In my symfony 2 app, I have a repository for my "departement" entity. In this repo, i have a method called getAvailableDepartements, that i use in a XXXType + Ajax to get all the departements that fit previous choices in the form:

```
public function getAvailableDepartements( $entites ) {

$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d');        
        $qb->where('d.entite IN :ents')
        ->setParameter('ents', $entites);                                     

        return $qb;
    }
```

My problem is about best practice, the code above doesn't work and I would like to know how other symfony devs would do what I try to achieve: retrieving all the departements that their "entite" field is IN the $entites Collection in parameter... I was thinking:

- foreach entity in entities, if ok populate local collections and return the merged collection that contains all departement ?
- or use kind of these:

  `public function findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null) {
  parent::findBy($criteria, $orderBy, $limit, $offset);

  }`

but it seems both ugly.

Thanks for your help and advices !

EDIT:
Call of this method in the XXType class:

```
    `$form->add('departements', 'entity', array( 
'class' => 'XXXperimetreBundle:Departement', 
'property' => 'sigle', 'multiple' => true, 
'expanded' => true, 
'query_builder' => function(DepartementRepository $dr) use ($entites) { return $er->getAvailableDepartements($entites); 
);`
```

Comment: show us your deparment entity definition and the relation "entite"

Comment: Here it is:
`/**          
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="XXX\perimetreBundle\Entity\EntiteResponsable")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
*/  
private $entite;`

Comment: And the departement one:
`/**
 * Departement
 * 
 * @ORM\Table(name="departements")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="XXX\perimetreBundle\Entity\DepartementRepository")
 */
class Departement
{`

Comment: `public function getAvailableDepartements( $entites ) {           $depts = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection();
$dept = Array();        
foreach ($entites->toArray() as $ent){  
$dept = $this->findBy(Array('entite' => $ent));
foreach($dept as $d){
if(!$depts->contains($d))
$depts->add ($d);
}
}
return $depts;
}`

I have written this, which works but doesnt get me expected result.

Comment: Have you tried using expressions? Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6319643

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
I tried this:
`$arr = $entites->toArray();
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d');        
$qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->in('d.entite', '?param'));
$qb->setParameter('param', $arr);        
        
return $qb;`
But still doesnt work :( If i remove the where clause and setparameter it works.

Comment: Hello ? Please people, im asking for good practices, i could do manual ugly query to fix this ! It's the same people that cry about bad code and don't give answers about good one...

Comment: if you answer with code, best is to edit your question and paste it there, so it is readable

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to return $qb ?

Try returning something like this:

```
$query = $qb->getQuery();
$result = $query->getResult(); // or $result = $query->getArrayResult();

return $result;
```

That's what my repository methods return.

Comment: Yeah i'm sure, because I use it in the POST_SUMBIT event of a XXXType form, and this is the following section of the callback closure that use the repo's method.
`$form->add('departements', 'entity', array(
   'class'    => 'XXXperimetreBundle:Departement',
   'property' => 'sigle',
   'multiple' => true,
   'expanded' => true,
    'query_builder' => function(DepartementRepository $dr) use ($entites)
                                {
                                    return $er->getAvailableDepartements($entites);
}));`
This is annoying yes, but Im trying to respect sep of concerns.