# Doctrine query WHERE IN - many to many

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am building out a hotel website in Symfony2. Each hotel can provide many board basis options such as Self Catering, All-Inclusive etc.

On my search form the users can filter by all of the usual fields such as location, price, star rating and board basis. Board basis is a multiple select check box.

When a user selects multiple board basis options, I am currently handling it in this way... (which is throwing errors)

```
$repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AppBundle:Accommodation");

$data = $form->getData();

$qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder("a")
        ->innerJoin("AppBundle:BoardType", "b")
        ->where("a.destination = :destination")
        ->setParameter("destination", $data['destination'])
        ->andWhere("a.status = 'publish'");

if (count($data['boardBasis']) > 0) {
    $ids = array_map(function($boardBasis) {
        return $boardBasis->getId();
    }, $data['boardBasis']->toArray());

    $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->in("a.boardBasis", ":ids"))
        ->setParameter("ids", $ids);
}
```

Here is the property declaration on a hotel entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="BoardType")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="accommodation_board_type",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="accommodation_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="board_type_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $boardBasis;
```

The error I am currently getting is:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 177 near 'boardBasis I': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.

On submitting the form and using `var_dump` on the board types I am getting:

```
object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)[3043]
  private 'elements' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        object(AppBundle\Entity\BoardType)[1860]
          protected 'shortCode' => string 'AI' (length=2)
          protected 'id' => int 1
          protected 'name' => string 'All-Inclusive' (length=13)
          protected 'description' => null
          protected 'slug' => string 'all-inclusive' (length=13)
          protected 'created' => 
            object(DateTime)[1858]
              ...
          protected 'updated' => 
            object(DateTime)[1863]
              ...
      1 => 
        object(AppBundle\Entity\BoardType)[1869]
          protected 'shortCode' => string 'BB' (length=2)
          protected 'id' => int 2
          protected 'name' => string 'Bed & Breakfast' (length=15)
          protected 'description' => null
          protected 'slug' => string 'bed-breakfast' (length=13)
          protected 'created' => 
            object(DateTime)[1867]
              ...
          protected 'updated' => 
            object(DateTime)[1868]
              ...
```

I cannot seem to find the correct syntax for this query, I have done a few times in the past (and it was a pain each time), but I just cannot remember how it is done. I have tried without mapping the ID's, passing the `ArrayCollection` directly in.

The only thing I can think of at the moment is to switch it to using `createQuery` and using DQL and see if that makes any difference.

Any help with this issue would be appreciated, Thank you

Comment: if you know working DQL, but you dont know how to do it using QueryBuilder, why don't you post the DQL here. Otherwise you need to pos more information (all querybuilder calls).

Comment: DQL is another option to try, I can add the rest of the querybuilder, its quite simple

Comment: you're saying the attribute boardBasis is on Hotel entity, but then you are using a.boardBasis, which would mean it is on Accomodation entity ?

Comment: also check the top answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929036/how-to-use-where-in-with-doctrine-2 if youre using expr()->in correctly

Comment: @Miro hotel and accommodation are the same thing, im going through refactoring the name. The issue still persists and is not related to the actual name, its the join and conditions on the many-many join

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks to me like you're join is not fully complete. You were missing a statement describing what field to join on:

```
$qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder("a")
    ->innerJoin("AppBundle:BoardType", "b")
    ->where("a.boardBasis = b.id")
    ...
```

Or you could join like that:

```
$qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder("a")
    ->innerJoin("a.boardBasis", "b")
    ...
```

Then you can do add your `WHERE IN` statement like so:

```
$qb->andWhere('b.id IN (:ids)')
    ->setParameter('ids', $ids);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the first one throws the same error and the bottom one doesnt cause a crash, but doesnt work either I am afraid

Comment: Alright, I updated my answer, see if that works for you :)

Comment: I think that has got it, Just testing now. Update: Seems to be working fine, thanks for your help