# Query an array type with php array using doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony4

I need to query an mysql array type with php array by using doctrine.

This my db column is **dc2 type array** and contains values like this.

```
a:1:{i:0;s:3:"4wd";}
```

And this is my querybuilder query,

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c'); 
$qb->andWhere('c.equipment IN (:equipment)')
   ->setParameter('equipment', array('4wd'));
$qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

But unfortunately this query returns only null output. It would be great if someone can help solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found an answer with **REGEXP**, But for symfony 4 you need **DoctrineExtensionsBundle**

```
"beberlei/DoctrineExtensions": "0.3.x-dev",
```

in doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            string_functions:
                regexp: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Regexp
```

in repocitery

```
$equipment = implode("|", array('4wd', 'AbD'));
$qb->andWhere('REGEXP(c.equipment, :regexp) = true')
                    ->setParameter('regexp', $equipment);
```

These two threads were really helpful for the answer and background.
[MySQL LIKE IN()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127088/mysql-like-in) And [Regex with Doctrine 2 query builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574760/regex-with-doctrine-2-query-builder)

Answer (score 1):

To be clear about DC2 type, it does **NOT** exist in SQL. DC2 is a comment added by doctrine to specify that it is a **text** value containing an array.

So, you should select the column and fetch it first. Doctrine is gonna process it and give you an array afterward, so you can do whatever you wanna do with it.

You *could* possibly search in the text field with **LIKE** and filter, but this is bad practice, make an Equipment entity and add a ManyToMany relation between Equipment and your entity. Where clause with a ManyToMany relation well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37092202/4585634).

Comment: is there a way to use like in this situation?

Comment: Didn't try LIKE with DC2 field, but maybe. However, as I said, you should not do it.

Comment: I found an answer with regexp. But thanks so so much for your explanation and reply