# Symfony doctrine findby => columnValue is contained in

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

I have a User entity that have sectors associated (such as sector A,B,C and so on)

(Sector is an entity too)

Then I have a Document entity that have sectors associated too

I want to retrieve all Documents where its sectors are in the User entity...

How to do that with doctrine?

```
$repo    = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Document');
$sectors = $this->getUser()->getSectors();

$repo->findBy(['sectors'=>???]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This one should be enough:

```
$repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Document');
$sectors = $this->getUser()->getSectors();
$sectorIds = array_map(function($sector) { return $sector->getId(); }, $sectors);

$queryBuilder = $repo->createQueryBuilder('document');
$queryBuilder
    ->lefJoin('document.sectors', 'sector')
    ->where('sector.id IN (:sectorIds)')
    ->setParameter('sectorIds', $sectorIds);

$documents = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Inspired from [How to use WHERE IN with Doctrine 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929036/how-to-use-where-in-with-doctrine-2)

Comment: No, it will not work because Docs can have more than one sector. For example User has sectors A,B and Doc1 has sectors A,B,C, and Doc2 has sector A. So I need to retrieve ONLY (in this case) Doc2 (cause Doc1 as sector C too that User doesn't have)