# How to set multiple parameters for the same key in Doctrine Query

Tags: php, symfony4, doctrine-query

I'm setting up an advanced search for a jobboard and I need to find resumes by contract, knowing that a resume can have multiple contracts.

I have a form where you can choose which type of contract you are looking for (It's a ChoiceType::class with multiple => true)

In my repository :

```
public function findByContract(array $contract)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
        ->andWhere('r.contract = :con')
        ->setParameter('con', array($contract))
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

In my controller :

```
public function index(Request $request, ResumeRepository $resumeRepository)
{
    $formSearch = $this->createForm(ResumeSearchFormType::class);
    $formSearch->handleRequest($request);

    if ($formSearch->isSubmitted() && $formSearch->isValid()) {
        $data = $formSearch->getData();

        $r = $resumeRepository->findByContract($data->getContract());
        var_dump($r); die;
```

This var_dump() returns an empty array.

I don't know how to set multiple parameters for the same key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`IN` condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929036/how-to-use-where-in-with-doctrine-2):

```
public function findByContract(array $contract)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
        ->andWhere('r.contract IN (:contracts)')
        ->setParameter('contracts', $contract)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your answer, now I have several parameters set ! But my var_dump () still returns an empty array. Do you know why ?

Comment: Can you post `var_dump($contract)` result?

Comment: array (size=2)
  0 => string 'CDI' (length=3)
  1 => string 'CDD' (length=3)

Comment: Ok, if `r.contract == CDD or r.contract == CDI` you will get an items. If no so you can check a query string in symfony profiler.

Answer (score 0):

In my table resume in phpMyAdmin the column contract look like that :

[image]

And in the profiler, the runnable query is :

```
SELECT r0_.id AS id_0, r0_.city AS city_1, r0_.postal_code AS postal_code_2, r0_.salary AS salary_3, r0_.contract AS contract_4, r0_.experience AS experience_5, r0_.training AS training_6, r0_.motivations AS motivations_7, r0_.ext AS ext_8, r0_.name AS name_9 FROM resume r0_ WHERE r0_.contract IN ('CDI', 'CDD');
```

So there are many resumes where `r.contract == CDD` or `r.contract == CDI`, but the query still return an empty array